# How to route requests between docker containers

Tags: docker, routes

I have a cloud server where I host my web-services. Currently, there is only one docker container with JS + PHP + Mysql running on the server. It serves the web-service mysite.co. There are going to be more web-services. I want to host them on the same machine but in another docker container. I want to refactor and create a bunch of services and containers:

docker1 with MySQL --> DB for all services

docker2 with PHP + JS --> `platform.mysite.co`

docker3 with PHP + JS --> for `mysite.co`

docker4 with Python -->  `client.mysite.co`. It's REST-endpoints for clients (ideally accessible only by VPN)

With which tool can I route web-requests between containers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your exact problem.

If it is basic routing between three containers, you need a basic server (nginx, apache). 
Il you want to perform load balandinc as well as routing between nodes among a swarm or pods in kubernetes, you may choose one that is more docker-suited, such as [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/).

It sounds like you see containers are some sort of impenetrable bastion... while it is acually acting exactly like your non-containerized web servers. 
So the routing problems you have have the same solutions here... maybe a few more because docker add a few devoted solutions.